# An $L^1$ convergence problem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

Is the following true?

> If $X_n$ converges **almost surely** to a non-negative random variable $X$ having finite expectation, and if $E(X_n)$ converges to $E(X)$, then $E|X_n - X|$ converges to $0$?

I am not able to apply the dominated convergence theorem to solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the $X_n$ aren't required to be non-negative, then fixing a distribution on $\mathbb R$ such that every interval has positive measure, and letting $\mathbb R$ be the sample space, let $X=0$ and $X_n$ be a single period of a square wave starting at $n$ and of total integral $0$ such that the integral of the absolute value is always $1$. It will have to get taller and wider to make this happen. However, I think the statement might be true if everything is non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the statement is true if the random variables are non-negative.

**Hint:** By the triangle inequality and the positivity of the random variables, we have

$$(X_n+X)-|X_n-X| \geq 0.$$

Now write

$$2 \int X \, d\mathbb{P} = \int \liminf_{n \to \infty} (X_n+X-|X_n-X|) \, d\mathbb{P}$$

and apply Fatous lemma.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by saz, it is true if the random variables are non-negative. In general, it is not true: take $X_n$ a random variable taking the value $0$ with probability $1-n^{-2}$, $n^3$ with probability $1/(2n^2)$ and $-n^3$ with probability $1/(2n^2)$. Then $X_n\to 0$ almost surely, $\mathbb E[X_n]=0$ but $\mathbb E|X_n|=n$.